# Docker Swarm Service Container Not auto-starting when Stopped Manually

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have defined the given below configuration for my service in the docker-compose files.

To deploy I used the following command

```
docker stack up rmbcnetwork -c /root/blockchain/network-config/docker-compose/orderer2.yaml
```

I did a `docker service ls` to see the deployed service from the swarm manager.

Then I moved to **SERVER1** on which the service was deployed and stopped the container manually by issuing the `docker stop <con-id>` command. I expected the swarm to start the container again as the condition for restart has been defined as **on-failure** in the compose file but it didn't.

I had to go back to the swarm manager server and issue the `docker service update <service-id> --force` command to start the service container again.

Also on inspecting the service container the restart-policy doesn't contain the specified value in the compose file.

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  rmbcnetwork:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

services:


  orderer2:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4.2
    volumes:
      - /data/orderer/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]

      #Prometheus
      - ORDERER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9443
      - ORDERER_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus

      #RAFT Settings
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    ports:
      - target: 7050
        published: 7050
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    networks:
      rmbcnetwork:
        aliases:
          - orderer2.examples.com
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == SERVER1]
```

Comment: `docker-compose` != Swarm Mode. The latter uses `docker stack deploy`.

Comment: @BMitch I did a stack deploy.

Comment: But you're showing the `docker-compose` version number. Please include a complete example of your issue, with a complete yml file and commands run.

Comment: @BMitch updated the question. Please review the details again. Thanks